# Datetime breaks with business time start time in ggplot graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have time series data with random number of elements (1-14 days of observations), and I use date_breaks construction for ggplot.
I have to recalculate date_breaks period for every data because sometimes 2h looks good, sometimes 24h, it depends on amount of days in data, I use calculate_tick_x function for that (see code below). That functions looks bad but at least it works how I want.

Everything works fine except the fact that date breaks time are chosen randomly. What I need - always see 9AM on my graphs to realize when working days were started.

If date_breaks = 24h, I want to see 9-00 - 9-00,

- 12h: 9-00 - 21-00 - 9-00
- 8h: 9-00 - 17-00 - 1-00 - 9-00
- 4h: 9-00 - 13-00 - 17-00 - 21-00 - 01-00 - 05-00 - 09-00
- etc

How to reach that?

My example code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(900)


calculate_tick_x <- function (data){
    
    interval_length_hours <- round ( difftime(  max( data$datetime),  min (data$datetime), units = "hours") ,1)
    
    if (interval_length_hours<= 1) {
        ticks_interval <- "10 mins"
    } else if (interval_length_hours<= 2) {
        ticks_interval <- "20 mins"
    } else if (interval_length_hours<= 6) {
        ticks_interval <- "60 mins"
    }    else if (interval_length_hours <= 24) {
        ticks_interval <- "2 hours"
    }    else if (interval_length_hours <= 32) {
        ticks_interval <- "4 hours"
    }    else if (interval_length_hours <= 120) {
        ticks_interval <- "8 hours"
    } else if (interval_length_hours <= 360) {
        ticks_interval <- "24 hours"
    }  else {
        ticks_interval <- "48 hours"
    }
    
    return (ticks_interval)
    
}


data1 <- 
    data.frame(
        datetime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00") + 15*50001, "15 sec"),
        Value = sample(1:1000, 50002, replace = T),
        Instance = "A"
    )

ggplot(data1, aes(x=datetime, y=Value, color = Instance)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_datetime(
        date_breaks = calculate_tick_x(data1),
        labels = date_format("%b %d - %H:%M", tz="UTC"
        ) 
    ) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 25,
        vjust = 1.0,
        hjust = 1.0
    ))
```

My result, you see, date breaks are at 20-00 there:

[image]

Comment: I think you will need to calculate the breaks yourself, rather than just the spacing. You could do this with seq (see ?seq.POSIXt). case_when() will make your current function nicer

Comment: Good idea. But how to use seq.POSIXt and always get 9-00 marks in result vector?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `expand = c(0, 0)` otherwise your range will be automatically widened resulting in a shift in your date labels as it seems as you cannot give a "start" for your labels.

`scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = calculate_tick_x(data1), labels = scales::date_format("%b %d - %H:%M", tz="UTC"), expand = c(0, 0))`

[image]

Result with manually entering `date_breaks = "8 hours"`

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I used your code and got 7:00 - 7:00 - 7:00 for my data. I don't really see any pointing to 9-00 in your code. Break points are still chosen randomly.